# React Router - nested routes, hide parent component in child app

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have parent app which has routes:

```
  <Switch>
     <Route exact path="/" component={Root} />
     <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
     <Route path="/user/:id" component={User} />
     <Route path="/lists" component={Lists} />
     <Route path="/admin" component={SubApp} />
  </Switch>

  ...

return (
<div className="App">
  <Header/>
  {routes}
</div>
);
```

The `SubApp` has its own Router. What I want to achieve is that on certain `SubApp` route, the parent's app `<Header/>` will not be shown. I've tried multiple things like passing prop down to child app or setting routes where the `<Header/>` will be displayed, but as soon as the route goes to `<SubApp/>` the parent router gets obviously ignored. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: There are many ways of doing this, including: 1. the `Header` or `App` knows not to show anything on certain routes; 2. you use a higher-order component to explicitly add the header to pages that should have it; and 3. you rearrange your routes such that there's on Switch between admin routes and all the rest, then a nested Switch with the Header for the non-admin routes.

Comment: Show the SubApp code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe how would you do the 1st option if the parent app doesnt know which subapp route is currently active? Also cant use hoc because child app should not contain parent app components, its completely separated.

Comment: As shown below, you *can* know which route is currently active. I don't know which bit is the "child app", but you could use e.g. `component={withHeader(Root)}` in what you're showing. Beyond that I'd suggest you show a [mre] of whichever option you pick if you can't get it working.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Maybe this example is better to understand. You go to ```/admin``` (you are now in SubApp) then you go to ```/admin/panel``` - here you want the header to be hidden but the parent app still thinks its on ```/admin``` route until you refresh.